# Regex to print Substring and complete string using Java

Tags: java, regex

i have an input string with 20 Chars and Using regex in java i need to match the pattern with first 9 char and entire 20 char.Input String AA2098E0511111111111 and regex am using ([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})([a-zA-Z0-9]{20})
First group is matched and second group is not matched.

Need assistance on this

1. `([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})([a-zA-Z0-9]{20})` this matched only AA2098E05
2. `([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})` this matched AA2098E05 and 11111111111
3. i want regex to match AA2098E05 and AA2098E0511111111111

Comment: I suggest matching `^(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}))[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}$`. The first 9 characters will be saved in capture group 1, all 20 characters will be matched (sometimes referred to as capture group 0). This also asserts that the string contains 20 characters. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rCYtgY/1)

Comment: Also with `String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}";` you can refer to group(1) and group(0)

Comment: With your pattern `([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})` you are already doing that, and then you have 2 capture groups.

Comment: @g00se, better than my suggestion. Add anchors if desired, in case string presented had more than 20 characters (and therefore is invalid), such as `'My dog AA2098E0511111111111 has fleas!'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i Just modified the pattern (([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}) and now able to match.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get:

- match 1: AA2098E0511111111111
- group 1: AA2098E05
- group 2: AA2098E0511111111111

  `(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}))(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{20}))[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}`

### [image: test screenshot]

if you want to get:

- match 1: ""
- group 1: AA2098E05
- group 2: AA2098E0511111111111

  `(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}))(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]{20}))`

[image: test screenshot]

***. you can also replace [a-zA-Z0-9] with [\w&&[^_]]**

Comment: You really don't need any lookarounds here.

Comment: @Thefourthbird if he only wants to get the first 9 characters and whole 20 characters, it is true that any lookarounds is not needed, but he wants group 1 is first 9 and group 2 is whole 20, so it is.

Comment: I think this would also suffice: `(([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11})` with 2 groups, or `([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}` with the full match and group 1

Comment: @Thefourthbird group 1 is whole 20 characters and group 2 is first 9 for (([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}) ; only have one group for ([a-zA-Z0-9]{9})[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}. but you're right. In practice, both forms are sufficient.